# why axios.postForm working instead of axios.post

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

so, I try to login using API hosted in in webhost, but why my code doesn't work with axios.post and only works with axios.postForm?
what is axios.postForm? and i need to get data from the API too but it only works with axios.getUri. what is axios.getUri? I cannot use.then if I use axios.getUri
anyone can explain? thank you.

```
 try {
      const loginReq = await axios.postForm(
        "http://spdaapp.000webhostapp.com/api/auth/login",

        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            accept: "*/*",
          },

          username: field.username,
          password: field.password,
        }
      );
      const loginResp = await loginReq.data;
      setLoading(false);
      if (loginReq.status === 200) {
        console.log(field.username);
        console.log(loginResp);

        Cookie.set("token", loginResp.access_token);
        Cookie.set("role", loginResp.status);
        router.push("/admin/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const err = error as AxiosError;
      // console.log(err.response?.status);
      // console.log(err.response?.data);

      setLoading(false);
      setShowSnackbar(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you include your code ?

Comment: i already added my code.

Comment: if i do axios.post it is not going to work and immediately redirect to get method